# How to monitor a windows service whether it is running normally by C++ code?

Tags: c++, windows, service, monitor

I start my windows service and after that, what I want to do is to monitor it! Not start, stopped or crash, I can always detect its status and restart it when something goes wrong. Some C++ code will be appreciated a lot!! Thanks!

Comment: you need use [QueryServiceStatusEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684941(v=vs.85).aspx) or [QueryServiceStatus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684939(v=vs.85).aspx) - depend from which info you need

Comment: You'll have to define "normally". If the service is hung in some `while(true)`  loop, it will appear to be running normally.

Comment: @RbMm how can i get the target service handle in another monitor service ?

Comment: @MSalters not stopped or crash.

Comment: by [OpenService](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684330(v=vs.85).aspx) - if you have(know) service name - *lpServiceName*

Comment: @RbMm thanks, i will have a try!